# Calculating the Hessian for nonlinear objective functions

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, nonlinear-optimization

In least squares minimization, we minimize the sum of squares of the residuals: $f = ||b-Ax||_2 ^2 $

The Hessian of this matrix is given by $2A^TA$, and from the Hessian we can do the second partial derivative test for critical points.

Let's say we want to change the objective function: $f_1 = ||b-Ax||_2 ^k$ where $(k \neq 2)$, or $f_2 = exp(||b-Ax||_2 ^2) $.  Is there an easy way to calculate the Hessian for these new objective functions?

Comment: My first go-to resource for such problems is the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to offer two answers here.

First of all, both $f_1$ (for $k>0$) and $f_2$ have *exactly the same optimal solution* that $f$ does. That is to say, any minimizer of $f$ is going to minimize $f_1$ and $f_2$ as well. There's a reason why $\|b-Ax\|_2^2$ is the go-to objective function for $\ell_2$ norm minimization: because among all of the functions $\phi(\|Ax-b\|_2)$ one could consider, where $\phi$ is a strictly increasing function $\phi(y)=y^2$ is the best choice from a computational perspective, because it yields nice simple derivatives. As we'll see below, your examples $f_1$ and $f_2$ are more complex. Furthermore, for $0<k<1$, the function ceases to be convex, which complicates numerical solution methods.

(Note: if you're adding constraints on $x$, then some solvers are going to prefer $\phi(y)=y$; that is, they will prefer to work with the non-squared norm.)

Now let's assume you are truly determined to compute these derivatives. Given that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are just compositions of $f$ with a simple scalar function, you don't even need the matrix cookbook. A sensible application of the chain rule will suffice. But I agree that if you're going to start working with functions of vectors and matrices, you'll want that resource.

Given $h(x)\triangleq g(f(x))$, where $g$ is a scalar function, we have
$$\nabla h(x) = g'(f(x)) \nabla f(x), \quad \nabla^2 h(x) = g''(f(x)) (\nabla f(x))(\nabla f(x))^T + g'(f(x)) \nabla^2 f(x)$$
For $f(x)=\|b-Ax\|_2^2$, we have 
$$\nabla f(x) = 2A^TAx, \quad \nabla^2 f(x)=2A^TA$$
For $f_1$, we have
$$g(y) = y^{k/2} \quad g'(y) = (k/2) y^{k/2-1} \quad g''(y) = (k/2)(k/2-1)y^{k/2-2}$$
For $f_2$, we have
$$g(y) = g'(y) = g''(y) = e^y.$$
Therefore,
$$\nabla f_1(x) = k\|Ax-b\|_2^{k-2} A^TAx$$
$$\nabla^2 f_1(x) = k(k-2)\|Ax-b\|_2^{k-4} A^TAxx^TA^TA + k\|Ax-b\|_2^{k-2} A^TA$$
and
$$\nabla f_2(x) = 2 e^{\|Ax-b\|_2^2} A^TAx$$
$$\nabla^2 f_2(x) = 4 e^{\|Ax-b\|_2^2} A^TAxx^TA^TA + 2 e^{\|Ax-b\|_2^2} A^TA$$
Simplify per your preferences :-)